# I am facing issue in moving file into my desired folder

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, codeigniter

i need to move my file into my desired location but my file is not getting moved to folder so please help me.

```
   Here is the code of my controller "Sms_Controller".       

    $pic_file1 = $this->input->post('pic_file');
    $pic_file1 = str_replace( "\\", '/', $pic_file1);
    $filename = basename($pic_file1);



        $config['upload_path']          = BASEPATH. '../assets/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 1000;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('pic_file')){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('reg_dsa', $error);
        }else{

            //file is uploaded successfully
            //now get the file uploaded data 
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

            //get the uploaded file name


        }
```

Comment: You want to move it after the upload or you want to put it right into the folder in the upload?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the general code for uploading the files to the desired folder from the website root directory and uploadFolder in the root Directory.

```
/*------------------------ File Upload --------------------------- */


        $config['upload_path'] = './uploadFolder/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|jpg|jpeg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $filename = "";
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename')) {
            //$this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', $this->upload->display_errors());
        } else {
            $data1 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $filename = "" . $data1["upload_data"]["file_name"];
        }

$filename is the Filename required to store in the database
```

Comment: why are you load upload library two times

Comment: Sorry that was written by mistake i will edit the post. Thanks for the acknowledgement

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this code

```
                $config['upload_path']          = './assets/uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('pic_file'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                        print_r($error);

                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                        print_r($data);

                }
                die;
```